# In Scala, how does one write a class with a constructor, not all of whose arguments are class members?

Tags: scala, constructor

I want to write  class whose constructor takes two parameters, but the arguments are not actually members of the class. e.g.

```
class P(V1:Int, V2:Int) {
   val set = Set(V1, V2)
}
```

Having constructed the 'set', I don't actually care about V1 and V2. Is there a way of expressing this in Scala ?

Comment: I don't know Scala at all well, so here's a wild guess: if you don't refer to those parameters elsewhere, the compiler automatically optimises them away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, exactly like that. If the constructor arguments are not tagged with `val` or `var`, nor the class is a `case class`, then they'll be kept allocated if used inside methods (or `lazy val`, I suppose). If used just in the constructor, they won't be allocated with the object, not even as private fields.

Comment: But the parameters will still be in scope within the class, which can be surprising:
class Scope(i:Int) { def iCanSeeYou() = i + 3 }